# jQuery decimal places

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me why my `toFixed(2)` is not working?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.originalData').change(function () {
        $('.changedData').val($(this).val());
        $('.percentage').text('0%');

    });
    $('.changedData').change(function () {
        var changedData = $(this).val().length;
        var originalData = $('.originalData').val().length;

        var percentageOfChange = changedData / originalData * 100 - 100
        $('.percentage').text(percentageOfChange+.toFixed(2)'%');
    });
});
```

Comment: syntax error here: percentageOfChange+.toFixed(2)'%'

Comment: It's generally a good idea to check the error message in your JS console, and to at least make some effort at bug-fixing yourself before posting a question to SO. If you looked at that line carefully, you would realize that you're calling a method on the `+` sign. Also, your console would give you an `unexpected token .` error, or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'%'` and `+` are out of place.

`$('.percentage').text(percentageOfChange.toFixed(2) + '%');`

Comment: That seems to have killed the counting

Comment: killed counting? how do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `+` sign before `toFixed(2)`. Just remove it and it will work.